# combine two bash for loop in to one, maybe user different kind of loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /Users/uttambaral/code/zipcodes/*MYSQL-STANDARD.sql
do
    echo "Importing: $i"
    mysql --host=database-1.12345678  --user=admin --password=123456789 Validation < $i
    echo "waiting for import to finish"
done

for i in /Users/uttambaral/code/zipcodes/*database-STANDARD.sql
do
    echo "Importing: $i"
    mysql --host=database-1.ck1n4yzwola8  --user=admin --password=123456789 Validation < $i
    echo "waiting for import to finish"
done
```

this is my current code, and I am prettry new with scripting so I am not too sure on how to make this code smaller.

trying to consice this code using diffrent kind of loop, maybe while loop or until loop?

Comment: The main reason why I wouldn't put it into a single loop, is that `--host` value is different for your two basic loops. Therefore the logical way to refactor this, would be to write a function, which takes the SQL code (`$i`) and the value for `--host` as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a `case` statement?

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in /Users/uttambaral/code/zipcodes/*-STANDARD.sql; do
  case "$i" in
    *MYSQL-STANDARD.sql)
       echo "Importing: $i"
       mysql --host=database-1.12345678  --user=admin --password=123456789 Validation < "$i"
       echo "waiting for import to finish";;
    *database-STANDARD.sql)
       echo "Importing: $i"
       mysql --host=database-1.ck1n4yzwola8  --user=admin --password=123456789 Validation < "$i"
       echo "waiting for import to finish";;
  esac
done
```

Using `bash` With `extglob` and `nullglob`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob

for i in /Users/uttambaral/code/zipcodes/*@(MYSQL|database)-STANDARD.sql; do
  printf 'Importing: %s\n' "$i"
  case "$i" in
    *MYSQL-STANDARD.sql)
      mysql --host=database-1.12345678  --user=admin --password=123456789 Validation < "$i";;
    *database-STANDARD.sql)
      mysql --host=database-1.ck1n4yzwola8  --user=admin --password=123456789 Validation < "$i";;
  esac
  printf 'waiting for import to finish\n'
done
```

---

- See `help case`

Comment: If you use brace expansion, you don't need _extglob_. It's a matter of taste, of course.

Answer (score 0):

There's two opportunities to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) this code up.

---

> ```
> for i in /Users/uttambaral/code/zipcodes/*MYSQL-STANDARD.sql
> ...
> for i in /Users/uttambaral/code/zipcodes/*database-STANDARD.sql
> ```

Start with

```
set -e
cd /Users/uttambaral/code/zipcodes
```

Then you can introduce the wildcard filename globs more concisely.
Or define a `DIR` variable, and use that in each glob.

The `-e` option ensures we will immediately bail
with fatal error if the directory can't be accessed.

---

Break out the repeated code as a helper function.

```
import () {
    HOST=$1
    FILE=$2

    echo "Importing: $FILE"
    mysql --host=$HOST --user=admin --password=123456789 Validation < $FILE
    echo "waiting for import to finish"
}
```

Now your `for` loops can invoke

```
    import database-1.12345678 $i
```

or

```
    import database-1.ck1n4yzwola8 $i
```

Comment: `set -e` has weird corner cases. (`f(){cd /nowhere;true;} set -e; f || echo no; f;`) Maybe better to test explicitly for the failed `cd` ?

Comment: I don't understand the "merge the lists" remark, given that OP wanted to send 1st glob to host1 and 2nd glob to host2.

Comment: It _is_ legitimate to DRY it up by defining a function which accepts IDK maybe a quoted glob, maybe a list of files? But I judged that to be a unit testing nightmare for OP, who already has some things to work through. Better to keep it simple in this case.